# File validation for modification and correction

Tags: java, validation, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

My application (RCP plugin desktop based) is writing some config and text files for its further use, which can be modified by user.

**MY LOGIC:** I have written a validation logic with the help of last modification time and got validation whether file is changed or not.

**IMPROVEMENT NEEDED:** Now I want if user omit the changes then treat file as a valid one, which last modified time logic will treat as a invalid.

So what changes are required in my logic or any other move can i take.

**UPDATE:**

this is quite straight logic that i have taken: A map which hold the last modified time and get validated as...

```
if (lastModifiedMap.containsKey(f.getPath()))
        {
            long fileModTime = lastModifiedMap.get(f.getPath());

            if (f.lastModified() > fileModTime)
            {
                System.err
                .println(f.getName()
                        + "::file has changed");

                return false;
            }

            else if (f.lastModified() == fileModTime)
            {
                System.out.println("File is not modified");
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
```

Comment: Why dont  you put your code?

Comment: is it good to use hashing for file content for retaining it? what if files are more than 100?